# Son produit en marchant sur la neige

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

Quels sont les mots (non-onomatopées) pour décrire le son produit quand on marche sur une couche de neige épaisse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lorsque la neige est durcie, ou lorqu’elle se comprime un peu sous le poids des gens, on dit habituellement qu’elle **craque**.

Si la neige est est bien tapée et qu’il fait froid au point que le craquement est fort et désagréable, un peu comme le bruit du styromousse qui travaille, on peut dire qu’elle **crisse**.

Si une fine couche de glace recouvre la neige, je dis et entends souvent qu’elle **croustille**, mais ça semble [non-attesté](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neige+croustille%2C+neige+qui+croustille%2C+neige+croustillante&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=). Le bruit des petites plaques de glace qui s’éloignent du marcheur sur la suface glacée est un son que l’on pourrait qualifier de *cristallin*.

Quand la neige est gorgée d’eau et qu'elle défonce même sous le poids d’une personne en raquettes, les gens parlent plus souvent de sa tendance à l’effondrement, qui n’a rien à voir avec le son qu’elle fait, que du bruit qu’elle produit. En fouillant mon expérience, je crois qu’on dira qu’elle *défonce avec un bruit sourd*, ou qu’on fera le rapprochement avec *le bruit du tonnerre lointain*, mais je ne suis pas certain du mot exact qui décrirait le bruit.

Comment: Je pense qu'on peut faire confiance à un Québécois pour tout ce qui touche à la neige...  Apparemment [en Bretagne elle ferait critch](http://www.espace-sciences.org/archives/pourquoi-la-neige-fait-critch-quand-on-marche-dessus) c'est peut-être le son qui correspond à crisser ?

Answer (score 2):

Vous pouvez peut-être essayer de ressusciter « craqueter », ancien et éprouvé pour évoquer des craquements répétés et peu sonores.
Illustration et détails dans le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/craqueter/verbe).